# where to get the SP 2010 Enterprise Search Query sample?

Tags: search, sharepoint-2010

where to get the SP 2010 Enterprise Search Query sample?

With "Contains" and "Freetext" option.

i find the tool from complex but its not working in share point 2010 sites.

Is there any tool available to generate SP 2010 search Query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What tool from CodePlex did you try?

I use the SharePoint SearchCoder tool of zevenseas
http://mosssearchcoder.codeplex.com/

Comment: I have tried to use the application it give the below Error:System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Office.Server, Version=12.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified. File name: 'Microsoft.Office.Server, Version=12.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c'

Comment: Did you try the application on the SharePoint server itself or a local computer? Did you download the SP2010 version?